# Why can't I initialize this List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Why isn't this possible to do?

```
private ObservableList<List<String>> fnlData;
.
.
fnlData.get(i).get(indexC) = null;
```

It says:

[image: this happens]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fnlData.get(i).get(indexC)` is the value of a method call. You can't assign anything to the value of a method call.

You can initialize elements of your `List`s with `set` :

```
fnlData.get(i).set(indexC,null);
```

Of course, `fnlData.get(i)` must be initialized first.
And `set(indexC,null)` will only work if the List returned by `fnlData.get(i)` already contains at least `indexC+1` elements.